# Tap Gesture Gesture Recognizer in ListView not working

Tags: android, objective-c, listview, xamarin, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have this in my ViewModel:

```
public class MyClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    int taps = 0;
    ICommand tapCommand;

    public MyClass()
    {
        tapCommand = new Command(OnTapped);
    }

    public ICommand TapCommand
    {
        get { return tapCommand; }
    }

    void OnTapped(object s)
    {
        taps++;
        Debug.WriteLine("parameter: " + s);
    }
}
```

and this in the xaml:

```
<Image Source="delete.jpg" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20">
     <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
            CommandParameter="Image1" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
 </Image>
```

but when the image is clicked nothing appears in output log. What I'm missing ?

> Note 1: I've followed the guide [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/tap/)
>
> Note 2: I'm debugging on Android Device
>
> Update 1: full xaml [here](http://pastebin.com/QHSjZY2P)

Comment: Where is the listview? Is Image part of DataTemplate? Can you provide a little more xaml?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get [0:] parameter: Image1

Comment: question updated with full xaml pastebin link @YuriS

Comment: after some try I notice that the image tap outside the listview works, but inside the listview doesn't. @YuriS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not provided any code behind, so I had to create my own (see below).
You also would save me 15 minutes if commented out ListView IsEnabled="False"

When you set `Command="{Binding TapCommand}` the TapCommand corresponds to the TapCommand of the list item, not to the model itself. So, you have 2 options

1. You can implement click in MyItem (I don't think you want that, so partial code for it commented below in MyItem class)
2. Define context binding on image itself.
   Because of that our view model can be created few times - we don't want that, so the best solution is to define static resource of view model and use it everywhere on page.
   The solution is below (you will just need to modify some namespaces and change delte.png to your delete.jpg):

page xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonRendererDemo;assembly=ButtonRendererDemo"
             x:Class="ButtonRendererDemo.ImageTapComplexPage"
             BindingContext="{StaticResource viewModel}">

      <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <local:TapComplexViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </ContentPage.Resources>


 <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="text2" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <StackLayout Padding="0,20,0,20">
    <Button Text="text" Clicked="onclick" BackgroundColor="#009688"></Button>

    </StackLayout>
    <Label Text="List Type" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <ListView x:Name="lstItems" RowHeight="60" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" > <!--IsEnabled="False"-->
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="0,2,0,2">
              <StackLayout Padding="5,5,5,5">
                <Image Source="{Binding source}" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" />
              </StackLayout>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="1">
                <Label Text = "{Binding name}" HeightRequest="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Label Text = "{Binding data, StringFormat='{0:F0}'}" />
              </StackLayout>
              <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Padding="0,0,15,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="delete.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20">
                   <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <!--<TapGestureRecognizer 
                        Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="Image1" />-->
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=TapCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding name}" />
                 </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
              </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Code behind

```
namespace ButtonRendererDemo
{
    public partial class ImageTapComplexPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ImageTapComplexPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();        
        }

        void onclick(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {

        }
    }

    public class TapComplexViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        int taps = 0;
        ICommand tapCommand;

        public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items { get; private set; }
        public TapComplexViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>()
            {
                new MyItem { name="First", source="Icon.png", data=0.5f },
                new MyItem { name="Second", source="Icon.png", data=0.6f },
                new MyItem { name="Third", source="Icon.png", data=0.7f }
            };

            tapCommand = new Command(OnTapped);
        }

        public ICommand TapCommand
        {
            get { return tapCommand; }
        }

        void OnTapped(object s)
        {
            taps++;
            Debug.WriteLine("parameter: " + s);
        }



    }

    public class MyItem
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public float data { get; set; }

        //public ICommand TapCommand
        //{
        //    get { return new Command(() => { }); }
        //}
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you have a question how to pass that click to the page from your model you can create a separate question and let me know. I have that solution too.

Answer (score 1):

In the back end of the xaml file make sure u set the BindingContext to the view model: Something like this:

xaml.cs

```
public partial class TapInsideFrameXaml : ContentPage
    {   
        public TapInsideFrameXaml ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            // The TapViewModel contains the TapCommand which is wired up in Xaml
            BindingContext = new TapViewModel ();
        }
}
```

Also check:

On Menu > tools > options > debugging > General:

- Ensure "Redirect all output window text to the immediate window" is NOT checked

On Project Properties > Build:

- Configuration: Debug
- "Define DEBUG constant" is checked
- "Define TRACE constant" is checked

On the Output window:

- Show output from: Debug
- Right-click in the output window and ensure "Program output" is checked

Also make sure you are debugging using F5 and not Ctrl f5

Comment: u tried adding a breakpont and see if that command gets called?

Comment: where are you expecting the output log to be?

Comment: on image tap -> output:  parameter: Image1

Comment: Ok this is my last option, try Console.WriteLine()

Answer (score 0):

You declared the `PropertyChangedEvent` event but you never actually use it. Try this:

```
public class MyClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    int taps = 0;
    ICommand tapCommand;

    public MyClass()
    {
        tapCommand = new Command(OnTapped);
    }

    public ICommand TapCommand
    {
        get { return tapCommand; }
    }

    void OnTapped(object s)
    {
        taps++;
        Debug.WriteLine("parameter: " + s);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged ([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));
    }
}
```